# How can i change the value of a cell in my workbook and still have the 'find' function in my VBA query select the cell and search the data set?

Tags: excel, vba, find

I am currently trying use a macro to search a data set in my workbook for a specific cell value. I want my macro to automatically find the data relating to a specific value in a cell and then copy and paste that data into a new sheet. The issue I'm having is that the data set is going to change, as is the value in the cell that I'm searching for. The 'find' function in my VBA query looks at a distinct 'what: "" value'.
**For example:**

```
    ActiveCell.Offset(4, -1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Cells.Find(What:="132", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

I need the `What:="..."` to be able to change depending what i update that value with in the sheet. The value will always be available in the dataset.

Is there a way to find the data that matches whatever value is inputted to the particular cell. For this example, i'm looking at cell Range("A1").

See above.

Comment: Have you tried `What:=Range("A1")`?

Comment: `ActiveCell.Offset(4, -1).Range("A1").Select` is the same as `Range("A1").Select`.

Comment: @z32a7ul That's not correct. It is equivalent to `ActiveCell.Offset(4, -1).Cells(1, 1).Select` or simply `ActiveCell.Offset(4, -1).Select` since `ActiveCell` is a single cell. Please note `Range` and `Cells` are relative to their parents. E.g. `Range("B5").Range("A2")` is equivalent to `Range("B6")`

Comment: @SuperSymmetry: I didn't know that. So, it's even worse, as it is quite deceptive. It should be then `ActiveCell.Offset(4, -1).Select`.